# Is there a way to check if a certain number of indices of the close price timeseries have crossed above/below a moving average series in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to check if close prices have crossed above or below their 200 period ema by a certain number of bars.

I understand that the built-in ta.crossover() function calculates the boolean value based on only the current and previous indices, but I was wondering if it is possible to calculate this based on a certain number of historical bars also.

Many Thanks.

Comment: So, do you want to count number of crosses in the last x bars?

Comment: not quite, i'm looking to evaluate whether or not say the last 5 bars' closing prices are all above/below the moving average, i don't want it to trigger based on the crossing of one bar alone, if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `var` counter for that.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

sma = ta.sma(close, 50)

var cnt_up = 0
cnt_up := (close > sma) ? cnt_up + 1 : 0                    // Increase the counter if the price is above the SMA, reset otherwise

bg_col = (cnt_up > 5) ? color.new(color.green, 85) : na     // Check if the last 5 bars were above the SMA

plot(sma)
bgcolor(bg_col)
```

[image]